# Flutter app not compiling: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_facebook_auth"

Tags: flutter, facebook-authentication

firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_facebook_auth":
In Podfile:
flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook app events needs to update their ios sdk version. Or you can use :

```
flutter_facebook_auth: 3.5.0+1
```

- **don't use ^ in the version because this will install the lastest
  version 3.5.2**

source:
https://github.com/darwin-morocho/flutter-facebook-auth/issues/157

Answer (score 0):

You can use, in the meantime, the below dependencies in your Pubspec.yaml (these are compatible)

```
flutter_facebook_auth: 4.3.1
facebook_app_events: ^0.16.0
```

Hopefully facebook_app_events will be updated soon. You can follow the issue in [their GitHub page](https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/issues/243).